# Is there any way to view all event handlers of TextBox TextChanged event in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#, .net

When I add the textBox.TextChanged to watch list I get a message saying

```
The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.TextChanged'
can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
```

Is there any way to check what event's are called on text change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the debugger, open up the control and find whichever private variable contains the [EventHandlerList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist.aspx). Then find the event add/remove code for `TextChanged` so see which key is used - and examine the event handler list's entry for that key.

It's painful, but it should work.

Comment: For info, the key is `EventTextChanged`

Answer (score 1):

Not really; events are, by design, a closed box. There are hacky ways of getting at it, but they all require incestuous knowledge of the implementation (be it a field-like event, or an EventHandlerList, etc).

Why do you need this?

One other approach might be to get the TextBox pdb from the [MS symbol server](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx) so you can add a breakpoint (to `OnTextChanged`) and step through the TextBox code, and step into the delegate invoke... again, not ideal.