# Finding out who is listening for PropertyChangedEventHandler in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a WPF form and I am working with databinding. I get the events raised from INotifyPropertyChanged, but I want to see how to get a list of what items are listening, which i fire up the connected handler.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the scenario you're describing.  Do you have sample code?  As I read it, you're listening to an event on an object, and you want to discover, in your listener, who all the other listeners are.

Comment: I have asked a similar question. You might want see the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242745/is-there-any-way-to-view-all-event-handlers-of-textbox-textchanged-event-in-visua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with the Items that are listening ?

Do you want to know which controls are databound to your property , or do you want to have a list of eventhandlers that are wired to the PropertyChanged event ?

The latter can be done by calling GetInvocationList on the event.

Answer (score 0):

Call GetInvocationList() on your event instance.
U'll get an array of delegates (if any): Delegate[]. For each delegate u can inspect the Method property - to get the MethodInfo of the method that acts as the listener; or the Target property - to get the instance of the object on witch the listener method is defined

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers all, I managed to track it down to null references on a different property (quite a lucky find!)